# Class Factory do not work with isinstance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a version of python's `namedtuple` that takes the types of the fields, and double checks that the fields are the correct types at creation. In order to do this, I created a factory function that returns a custom class. However, it's impossible to use instances of these classes with `isinstance`. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Edit: To make the question more clear, neither of the if statements at the end of my code print anything, because the conditions evaluate to false. I'd like a simple way to determine which objects are instances of the class.

Code below.

```
from collections import namedtuple

# TYPED VERSION OF A NAMEDTUPLE                                                                                                                                                 
def typedtuple(name, fields, types):
    if len(fields) != len(types):
        raise TypeError("typedtuple must have the same number of fields and types")

    Base = namedtuple(name, fields)

    class TypedTuple(Base):

        def __new__(cls, *args):
            if len(fields) < len(args):
                raise TypeError("Too many arguments to typedtuple" 
                                "{}; got {} and expected {}".format(
                                    name, len(args), len(fields)
                                ))

            if len(fields) > len(args):
                raise TypeError("Not enough arguments to typedtuple"
                                "{}; got {} and expected {}".format(
                                    name, len(args), len(fields)
                                ))

            i = 0

            for a, t in zip(args, types):
                if not isinstance(a, t):
                    raise TypeError("Wrong type of argument to typedtuple"
                                    "{}; {} at position {} is not of type {}".format(
                                        name, a, i, t
                                    ))
                i += 1

            return Base(*args)

    TypedTuple.__name__ = name

    return TypedTuple


GaussianInteger = typedtuple("GaussianInteger", ["real", "imag"], [int, int])

point = GaussianInteger(1,2)

print point
print type(point)
print GaussianInteger

if isinstance(point, GaussianInteger):
    print "it is an instance"
if type(point) == GaussianInteger:
    print "it is the type of"
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the error?

Comment: Note, you don't have to check if there are too many/ too little arguments, `namedtuple` types already do that. Additionally, you should really have `__slots__ = ()` in your `TypedTuple` class definition, or else each namedtuple will carry around a dictionary! Probably defeating the entire purpose of using a named-tuple

Comment: Why is your `__new__` returning an instance of `Base`?